# Regex for a letter followed by space and quotations ( ")

Tags: python

I'm iterating over a list of JSON objects and want to find every occurrence of any letter followed by a space and then a quotation mark so that:

MATCH:
`"Some words here "`

NO MATCH:
`"Some words here"`

This is what I'm trying but it does not work:

```
for i in range (len(json_list)):
     m = re.search('(?=[a-z])(*\s)(?=\")', json_list[i])
     print (m.group(0))
```

Failing as such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api_extraspace.py", line 13, in <module>
    print (m.group(0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: What is `(*\s)` supposed to mean?

Comment: If the regular expression doesn't match, `re.search()` returns `None`. You need to check for this before trying to use `m.group(0)`

Comment: Try `r'\w+\s*"'`

Comment: @geckos `\w` matches numbers and underscore, not just letters.

Comment: So `([a-z]+\s*)"` !?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, above should say: '(?=[a-z])(\s)(?=\")'

Comment: @ddNip You can [edit] to fix it

Comment: @geckos i tried ([a-z]+\s*)" but it is not matching.

[
                    "equals",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "details",
                        "SERVICEDESC"
                    ],
                    "SERVICENAME "
                ]

The code should match the "SERVICENAME " line and return it so i can fix the trailing space

Comment: Don't use `*` after `\s`. The space is required, but that makes it optional.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your lookbehind is missing the less-than sign: `(?=[a-z])` -> `(?<=[a-z])`
2. `(*\s)` is invalid. I think you want `\s+`.

Here's a working example:

```
import re
for s in ['"Some words here"', '"Some words here "']:
    m = re.search('(?<=[a-z])\s+(?=")', s)
    print(repr(s), m)
```

Output:

```
'"Some words here"' None
'"Some words here "' <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 17), match=' '>
```

Comment: From a comment, it looks like he eventually wants to do `re.sub()` to remove the space, so this is better than my answer with a capture group.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, you don't need lookaround for `re.sub`! You can use capture groups, like `re.sub(r'([a-z])\s+(")', r'\1\2', ...)`. BTW I thought your answer was useful as another perspective.

Comment: Yeah, but lookarounds make it cleaner.